# Calling a Field within an Object in an Async Function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In my Node.js code, the server console returns the object gameFind with a populated value for hikeEnd (it's a Date field), but the console result for gameFind.hikeEnd, called immediately after, is undefined. This makes my equation NaN. What am I doing wrong here?

```
        async function saveHike() {
            await Game.updateOne({},{ $set: { hikeEnd: Date.now() } });
            
            var gameFind = await Game.find( { teamName: thisTeam } );
            console.log ('gameFind: ' + gameFind);
            console.log ('gameFind.hikeEnd: ' + gameFind.hikeEnd);
            //calculate the score
            var hikeScore = (gameFind.hikeEnd - gameFind.hikeStart) / 1000;
            console.log ('hikeScore: ' + hikeScore);

        }
        saveHike();
```

EDIT: console.log output

```
gameFind: {
  _id: new ObjectId("62df29b4ea65773e6827aa54"),
  teamName: 'a',
  captain: 's',
  score: 0,
  startTime: 2022-07-25T23:39:32.235Z,
  leavetakingsEnd: 2022-07-25T23:39:32.248Z,
  hikeStart: 2022-07-25T23:39:32.252Z,
  hikeVotes: 1,
  hikeEnd: 2022-07-25T23:39:53.835Z,
  townStart: 2022-07-25T23:39:53.838Z,
  townEnd: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z,
  __v: 0
}
hikeEnd: undefined
hikeScore: NaN
```

Given Seth's comments, I suppose this must be an async/await issue, but I cannot determine it. I have tried calling it with gameFind[hikeEnd] rather than a dot call but it still logs undefined. Is await Game.find being executed AFTER the console.logs because it's in an await? This must be it, but I can't remedy it. Thanks in advance, this has gotten quite frustrating.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include what the console output is? I have a suspicion that gameFInd doesn't have a field called "hikeEnd". We might be looking at a typo or something.

Answer (score 1):

I made a version of your code that doesn't execute from the database just to see if I could mirror your output. I cannot.

Here is my code,

```js
var globalGameFind= {
  teamName: 'a',
  captain: 's',
  score: 0,
  startTime: new Date("2022-07-25T23:39:32.235Z"),
  leavetakingsEnd: new Date("2022-07-25T23:39:32.248Z"),
  hikeStart: new Date("2022-07-25T23:39:32.252Z"),
  hikeVotes: 1,
  hikeEnd: new Date("2022-07-25T23:39:53.835Z"),
  townStart: new Date("2022-07-25T23:39:53.838Z"),
  townEnd: new Date("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
  __v: 0
}
function saveHike() {
  var gameFind = globalGameFind;
  console.log('gameFind: ' + gameFind);
  console.log('gameFind.hikeEnd: ' + gameFind.hikeEnd);
  //calculate the score
  var hikeScore = (gameFind.hikeEnd - gameFind.hikeStart) / 1000;
  console.log('hikeScore: ' + hikeScore);

}
saveHike();
```

And here is my output

gameFind:

```json
{
    "teamName": "a",
    "captain": "s",
    "score": 0,
    "startTime": "2022-07-25T23:39:32.235Z",
    "leavetakingsEnd": "2022-07-25T23:39:32.248Z",
    "hikeStart": "2022-07-25T23:39:32.252Z",
    "hikeVotes": 1,
    "hikeEnd": "2022-07-25T23:39:53.835Z",
    "townStart": "2022-07-25T23:39:53.838Z",
    "townEnd": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

gameFind.hikeEnd: Mon Jul 25 2022 16:39:53 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

hikeScore: 21.583

What's likely happening for you is gameFind.hikeEnd is undefined because gameFind doesn't have a field called hikeEnd on it.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks very much. So this could be an async/await issue?

Comment: I'm having trouble diagnosing this problem. The gameFind object clearly is populated with the fields needed, but any logs for its fields (gameFind.hikeEnd, gameFind.teamName) return as undefined. When I log gameFind again after gameFind.hikeEnd, it shows it's populated. Is this some sort of async/await issues (which I admit I suck at)? I just don't get how the logs can show the full object but can't pull the fields within it.

Comment: I don't think it's an async issue. Are you coding this in the browser? You might be able to use break points to help you diagnose this.

Even if it's not in the browser, VS code might be able to help

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate solution was to change my `Game.find` to `Game.findOne` so it returns a document rather than a cursor.